# Does it have to be hard to overload functions across namespaces?

Tags: c++, coding-style, namespaces, overloading

I have been writing some code with basically this structure

```
namespace util {
    void read (int &);
    template <typename T>
    void read (T &);
}

void foo ();

using namespace util;

namespace { // A
    void read (MyType &, int);

    void do_something () {
        MyType t;
        int i;
        // using util::read; // B
        read (i); // C
        read (t,i); // D
    }
}

void foo () {
    do_something ();
}
```

At first line C wasn't compiling unless I fully qualify it as `util::read(i)` or uncommented line B, but that makes line D fail.

Specialising the template util::read isn't possible because the number of arguments is different (until C++0x).

Turning line A into `namespace util` isn't an option because I don't want to export the new `read`.

I could rename `read(MyType&,int)` but that breaks *ahem* style.

Is there a way to make these cross-namespace overloads work nicely? Is there a good reason that they shouldn't?

Comment: What error do you have when decommenting line B.  I see no problem with it (and g++ 4.4.4 neither).

Comment: You could always skip `using namespace util;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's hard. In fact, it's impossible.

The best you can do is to hide names. You're right to employ `using` (B) to get around the complications that name hiding brings into the mix, when you're also overloading functions — D should still function in this case. Please show the error you got for it.

Answer (score 0):

Different namespaces mean different full names of identifiers contained in them so they are not overloads of each other (at least for Microsoft's compiler and GCC - I'm not sure how the standard defines).

Try this:

```
namespace util {
    void read (int &);
    template <typename T>
    void read (T &);
}

void foo ();

namespace { // A
    using ::util::read;
    void read (MyType &, int);

    void do_something () {
        MyType t;
        int i;
        // using util::read; // B
        read (i); // C
        read (t,i); // D
    }
}

void foo () {
    do_something ();
}
```